# Laravel eloquent orderby related model's column sum (has Many Relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Need a solution to list user based on maximum credits won (sum of amount column in winnings) .
Two models User and Winning . 
User has many winnings .

```
 $top_scorers = User::with('winnings')->orderBy("sum of amount column in all winnings")
```

Comment: I have to order by sum of a column in related model not related models count ..@ApródIllés

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you go at it the other way around:

```
 $usersByWinnings = Winning::with('user')
       ->select('user_id', \DB::raw('SUM(amount) as winnings'))
       ->groupBy('user_id')
       ->orderBy('winnings', 'DESC')
       ->get()->map(function (Winning $winning) {
             return $winning->user;
        });
```

Alternatively you can do a post-processing sortBy

```
$top_scorers = User::with('winnings')->get()
                  ->sortByDesc(function (User $user) {
                       return $user->winnings->sum('amount');
                   });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a modified `withCount()`:

```
$top_scorers = User::withCount(['winnings as amount' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(amount)'));
}])->orderByDesc('amount')->get();
```