# Laravel eloquent order by sum of hasMany or by join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sum, sql-order-by

I would like to order my products by the those who do have the most likes. I have one products table, one likes table and one users table.

This is how my likes table looks like:
`id, user_id, product_id, value`

The `value` can either be `1` or `-1` which is equal to one like or one dislike.

In my products model I have defined those relationships:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'products_likes', 'product_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('value')->withTimestamps();
}

public function productLikes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductLike');
}
```

However, now I would like to get the first 20 products which have the most `sum` of likes.
This is how I tried to solve this, however, I cannot solve my problem...

```
$products = Product::select('products.*', DB::raw('SUM(products_likes.value) as sumLikes'))
            ->join('products_likes', 'products_likes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->orderBy('sumLikes', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

However, this results in a weird group by sql problem:

```
QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `products`.*, SUM(products_likes.value) as sumLikes from `products` inner join `products_likes` on `products_likes`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` order by `sumLikes` desc)
```

Does anyone knows how I can archive this?
I want to have my database to perform the ordering job and not Laravel. I have found some solutions here as well but they suggest to perform an `all()` and `with("likes")` query and use `sortByDesc` after the query got executed ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55179546/9445999)). But this brings down performance.

Kind regards

Comment: There's nothing weird about that error: If you use an aggregation function (COUNT, SUM, etc) all other columns on your select must be part of your GROUP BY clause

Comment: But why is that and is there a better way to perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

From laravel 5.2 onwards, you can use the `withCount` method to add a 'likes_count' subquery column, which can be customized like this:

```
Product::query()
    ->withCount(['likes as sumLikes' => function ($query) {
        return $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(products_likes.value) AS sumLikes'));
    }])
    ->orderBy('sumLikes', 'DESC')
;
```

A similar result can be achieved on Laravel 5.1 or older versions by writing the subquery yourself:

```
$subquery = ProductLike::query()
    ->selectRaw('SUM(product_likes.value) as sumLikes')
    ->whereRaw('product_likes.product_id = products.id')
;
Product::query()
    ->addSelect(DB::raw($subquery->toSql()))
    ->orderBy('sumLikes', 'DESC')
;
```

Another way would be using joins, like you were attempting to, but you need to GROUP BY the products for it to work.

```
Product::query()
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(products_likes.value) as sumLikes'))
    ->join('products_likes', 'products_likes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderBy('sumLikes', 'DESC')
;
```

You may need to specify the columns in your select, and group by each one of them, depending on your Database Engine.

Comment: I have tried the answer above and the last one. The first one is not working for me. I don't know why but Laravel makes a subquery with `count(*)` instead of `sum(value)`... I don't know why, do you? The third answer is giving me back items multiple times because of the `join`. Do you know how to fix the first answer?

Comment: For some reason it worked for me with DB::Raw, but not with select raw